# How to efficiently use the result of this calculation two times?

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new to Haskell and I'm currently working on my first project. I've written a function that returns something based on a call to another function, that calls this function again (so it's recursive).

```
function :: a -> a
function a
  | null (recursive call) = a
  | otherwise = head (same recursive call)
```

How can I only make the recursive call once and use the result twice (as a condition and as part of the 'return value')?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function a
  | null recCall  = a
  | otherwise     = head recCall
 where recCall = recursive call
```

But this is not a good approach. Avoid using `head`, `tail`, `!!`. Generally there's something called “boolean blindness”: using boolean values means the program basically forgets the meaning of what you're basing your logic on, which means you need to re-introduce it, which makes your programs both more verbose and less reliable.

Better just use *pattern matching* on the recursion-result right away:

```
function a = case recursive call of
   [] -> a
   (h:_) -> h
```

This can also written with *pattern guard* syntax

```
function a
  | (h:_) <- recursive call  = h
  | otherwise                = a
```

Comment: You could delegate the pattern-matching to `foldr`: `function a = foldr const a (recursive call)`.

Answer (score 1):

While the formulations suggested by @leftroundabout are almost certainly superior programming style, I'd point out that you'd be hard-pressed to find an example where GHC didn't recognize the repeated calls and lift them to a single call, so from the standpoint of code efficiency -- as opposed to good programming style -- there's usually not much point in trying to eliminate this kind of duplication.

This can be important in other contexts, if you find yourself trying to choose between a straightforward way of writing something that involves some unnecessary duplication versus a really awkward or messy way that eliminates any duplication.  Write whichever one makes for better *source*  code, code that's easier to read and maintain and understand, and trust that the compiler will avoid unnecessary duplicate calls.

For example, there are far too many people -- myself included -- who are tempted to rewrite a tree-searching function:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

find1 :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Maybe a
find1 x (Leaf) = Nothing
find1 x (Node y l r) = case compare x y of
  LT -> find1 x l
  GT -> find1 x r
  EQ -> Just y
```

with a helper to avoid unnecessarily passing the fixed parameter `x`:

```
find2 :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Maybe a
find2 x = go
  where go Leaf = Nothing
        go (Node y l r) = case compare x y of
          LT -> find2 x l
          GT -> find2 x r
          EQ -> Just y
```

If you think `find2` is clearer than `find1`, by all means write it that way.  If you think you're writing more efficient code, think again.  Compile with:

```
ghc -O2 -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques Tree.hs
```

if you'd like to check for yourself that the core generated for `find2` is:

```
find2 = find1
```

The same holds for your example.  I'm hard-pressed to come up with something realistic, but consider your version and @leftroundabout's versions of the following rather pointless function:

```
foo1 :: a -> a
foo1 a | null (foo1 [a]) = a
       | otherwise = head (foo1 [a])

foo2 :: a -> a
foo2 a = case foo2 [a] of
  [] -> a
  (h:_) -> h

foo3 :: a -> a
foo3 a | (h:_) <- foo3 [a] = h
       | otherwise         = a
```

Would it surprise you that the core generated for `foo2` and `foo3` is the following?

```
foo2 = foo1
foo3 = foo1
```

Comment: Can't agree. For one thing, in 90% of cases the version without duplication **is** the better one source-wise – at least as readable, and importantly much more reliable for future changes. And your assertion that GHC will usually eliminate duplication is just not true – this is in general impossible, not something GHC terribly emphasizes because it just [doesn't work well, can have detrimental effects](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/more-cse), and is somewhat pointless since good source shouldn't have much duplication to begin with.

Comment: And even if you've established that some given duplicative code _is_ CSE-optimised, this can be a really dangerous thing to depend on – it can easily break with different circumstances / optimisation settings, and if this is in recursive calls than the performance hit may be vast (like, turning linear into exponential complexity).

Comment: Well, you can say "90% of cases", but it seems hard to quantify.  I mean, I see a **lot** of examples of `find x = go` and similar in base libraries, and I frequently write functions that way myself.  But, objectively, it doesn't strike me as more readable, significantly more reliable for future changes, or ever in much danger of going unoptimized.  As for optimizations that can easily break, the same can be said of fusion or unboxing or strictness analysis or a dozen other things Haskell programmers rely on every day.